# Navigation Bar Overlaps Info

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, navigationbar

I am having a problem with my navigation Bars overlapping the Information on the top of the iPhone. I originally had the navigation bar as White/ Translucent and it didn't cause a problem. I feel that making it black would be better except for now it overlaps the Time, Battery and Data from the iPhone. How would I move the navigation bar down?

[image: Navigation Bar looks Bad. Need to drop it down]

Comment: You want to increase the NavigationBar size a little larger?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom `navigationBar` and then add the constraints that you want, but this is not something that should interrupt with the status bar usually. You could try to change the font size of your `navigationBar` text:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)]
```

**Update:**
After some clarification, you don´t want to move done the `navigationBar`, you just want to change the color of the `statusBar` (which contains all system icons on the top). Add these two rows in your `viewDidLoad` function to change the background color of you:

```
if let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Comment: Would this be in the View Controller? What if I have a bunch of view controllers? Would I have to put these in every one?

Comment: Do you mean the changed font or the custom navigation bar?

Comment: No, I want the the black background to be moved down by a few points, and have the very top of the screen look white.

Comment: @RyanB., did you manage to solve your issue with the update above?

Answer (score 0):

Just make this class parent class of your every `viewController`
For example you have a `SignUpViewController` class and currently your this view controller will be like this.

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
//Your all methods and properties are implemented here.

}
```

So just change the parent class of above class from `UIViewController` to below written class `LargerNavigationBaseVC` like this.

```
class SignUpViewController: LargerNavigationBaseVC {
//Your all methods and properties are implemented here.

}


class LargerNavigationBaseVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationItem.prompt = " "
    }
}
```